# how can use jsonkit to get data form website (created in wordpress) which enabled with json plugin

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, wordpress

I want to create a ios project in which get data from website which is created in word press and json plugin enabled in word press. But i am getting html code as string when request with any url of website . It should be in json format so that i can parse it in relevant information.

So please help me how can perform done this task.